# To transact an amount less than minimum transaction amount

Tags: transactions

Lets consider minimum bitcoin transaction amount is $10 and is it possible to send an amount which is less than $10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send even 1 satoshi

But you will be forced to pay 10000 satoshis as transaction fee.

For example https://blockchain.info/tx/35189b74ac7e0cd8fb723b450f8d63f9b52b628dc5dd3599eadde8d1bbd2a332 sends 0.00000001 btc from 1Fri3h6MtMkjZjYHub4r1N6r5nERWgZXHQ to 13MePxVWGvK2qxd3vhef2Wf79zYQiGNwQL with the fee 0.0001 btc

In general. Lets assume that I can not send you $0.01 (one cent). I will send you $100.01 and you will return me $100.00 back. So, "minimum" rule is useless

Comment: Sending back $100.00 would require a change address for the 0.01 which means you run into the 10k satoshi txfee again.

Comment: I will send 2 inputs + 2 outputs (for example: 100.01 + 5.00 => 100.00 + 5.01 change to myself)